# Why can one not combine a variable and a function in an if-statement using PowerShell?

Tags: function, variables, powershell, if-statement

Running:

```bash
$a = "HelloWorld"

if ($a -and b) {Write-Host "helloworld"}

function b { return "HelloWorld"}
```

returns:

```bash
At C:\Users\r\Desktop\test.ps1:24 char:12
+ if ($a -and b) {Write-Host "helloworld"}
+            ~
You must provide a value expression following the '-and' operator.
At C:\Users\r\Desktop\test.ps1:24 char:13
+ if ($a -and b) {Write-Host "helloworld"}
+             ~
Unexpected token 'b' in expression or statement.
At C:\Users\r\Desktop\test.ps1:24 char:13
+ if ($a -and b) {Write-Host "helloworld"}
+             ~
Missing closing ')' after expression in 'if' statement.
At C:\Users\r\Desktop\test.ps1:24 char:14
+ if ($a -and b) {Write-Host "helloworld"}
+              ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

**Workaround**

```bash
if ($a) {
  if (b) {
    Write-Host "helloworld"
  }
}
```

results in:

```bash
helloworld
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All about order. Here's the solution:

```powershell
function b { return "HelloWorld"}

$a = "HelloWorld"

if ($a -and (b)) {Write-Host "helloworld"}
```

**First point:** The function needs to have been defined by the time you try and call it. If the definition is after the call it will fail because it doesn't exist yet.

**Second point:** You need to evaluate the returned value from the function before trying to compare something with it, therefore you need to use parenthesis around the call to ensure it gets executed *before* the logical operation.

Comment: Yep, Powershell is an interpreted (not compiled) language, which means stuff has to exist before you can refer to it since the parser is running through the file sequentially.

Comment: @JNK, not really about interpreted/compiled (e.g. Python is compiled but would show the same behaviour) rather it's because functions are looked up in a dynamic namespace so you can add/remove/redefine them at will and the current definition at time of call is what matters.